How to set TDownloadWizardPage progress bar to match the file size?
How to set TDownloadWizardPage progress bar to match the real size of file? Now the progress bar is not reaching 100% when the file completes.
Is there a method to configure it, when the size is known beforehand e.g. 10MB?
